# How to setup arrays in my case

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I need to create a array like the following

```
var new = 'New';
var old = 'Old';
var posterArray = [new, old]; 

//I want to push posterType and posterYear into new and old array
var posterType = [{'id':123, 'name':'test'}, {'id':456, 'name':'test'}];
var posterYear = [{'year':12345, 'status':'old'}, {'year': 3456, 'name':'old'}];
```

Is there anyway I can push `posterType` and `posterYear` into `new` and `old` variable inside the `posterArray`? For example, `posterArray[0].push(postertype)`. Basically I need mullti-dimentional array and I am not sure how to accomplish here. Thanks for the help!

Comment: `new` and `old` are strings. It's not clear to me what exactly you want to "push" there.

Comment: I want to make the string become variables. Would that be possible?

Comment: String is a data type. Values can be of type String. Values can be assigned to variables. I don't understand what you mean by "make the string become variables".

Comment: Be careful with the name `new` since that is a keyword.

Comment: If you want `posterArray[0].push(postertype)` to work, then create an array of arrays: `var posterArray = [[], []];`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like this would suffice your needs:

```
var posterArray = {
   new:  null,
   old: null
};
```

Then later on:

```
posterArray.new = [{'id':123, 'name':'test'}, {'id':456, 'name':'test'}];
posterArray.old = [{'year':12345, 'status':'old'}, {'year': 3456, 'name':'old'}];
```

And you can even do:

```
var newObj = {
   id:  234,
   name: 'newtest'
};

posterArray.new.push(newObj);
```

**EDIT** Also heed  ryanyuyu's warning:  `new` is a reserved keyword in javascript